# Can cables affect Wlan connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, cable, signal

Do different cables (One coax, 5-6 power cables, one HDMI, two Ethernet CAT 5e) effect a WLAN signal? Im asking because my wlan throughput rate is jumping between a poor signal and optimum, where the signal itself stays at almost full (-48dbm, 2.4ghz). The connection drops make it impossible to play multilayer games and this is annoying.
When the wlan is working I get a 2-3ms ping to the router and about 10-15ms to the outside, with full 100k of speed.
I couldn't test to move the router away because I don't have a longer cable to connect the router to the "wallpanel" (Where the cable from the ISP comes out) and the cables are fixed on the wall too, so I would like to know your opinion before starting to move everything.
I already switched channels and tested for other sources of interference.

Answer (score 0):

No. Cables in the surrounding of the router should not be able to interfere the signal because they are shielded and there's not much current going through them. A wireless signal can be interfered by another wireless signal, such as those of handheld telephones (seen this one too many times to be funny), or from large steel objects where the signal simply gets blocked.

But if a wifi signal is poor, it usually means that another wifi signal is close and on the same channel. The first thing I would do is measure all nearby wifi signals by channel (there are great apps for mobile phones (free) that allow you to do that, but also for windows (pc) if you use a laptop or desktop with wireless card. Find a free channel, and change your router to work on that channel instead. Will likely solve your problem. If your router already is on a (nearly) empty channel, change it to another (nearly) empty channel.

Also, make sure the router antenna(s) is/are pointed up for the best performance.